# How to accumulate the enumerable into the categories with accumulated value for each category?

Tags: elixir

How I can reduce the list of tuples into a list of sums per categories?

```
l = [{:a, 3}, {:b, 5}, {:c, 3}, {:a, 6}, {:b, 3}, {:a, 3}] 
sum_by_category = ...reduce_by... 
sum_by_category = [{:a, 12},{:b, 8},{:c, 3}]
```

It should be a function like `reduce_by(enumerable, acc, accumulation_fun, key_fun)`
where

1. "acc" and "accumulation_fun" work like in Enum.reduce, and
2. "key_fun" works like in Enum.group_by.

Comment: Shouldn't the resulting ```sum_by_category``` be ```sum_by_category = [{:a, 12},{:b, 8},{:c, 3}]```, with a sum of 12 for category a?

Comment: Stephen, you are absolutely right. I have fixed the question to show the correct value. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you could use `Enum.group_by/3` to get a more organized enumerable, you'd still have to traverse the resulting list, so I think the most efficient solution here would to use humble `Enum.reduce/3`:

```
l = [{:a, 3}, {:b, 5}, {:c, 3}, {:a, 6}, {:b, 3}, {:a, 3}]


summed = Enum.reduce(l, %{}, fn {k, v}, acc ->
  existing = Map.get(acc, k, 0)
  Map.put(acc, k, existing + v)
end)
IO.inspect(summed)
# yields:
# %{a: 12, b: 8, c: 3}
```

Use `Enum.to_list/1` to convert the result back to a keyword list if needed.

Comment: This is realy cool. It works also if you use Keyword instead of Map: `summed = Enum.reduce(l, [], fn {k, v}, acc ->
  existing = Keyword.get(acc, k, 0)
  Keyword.put(acc, k, existing + v)
end)
IO.inspect(summed) `

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can use [`for`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) with [`reduce`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1-the-reduce-option) option:

```
for {e, n} <- l, reduce: [] do
  acc -> Keyword.update(acc, e, n, &(&1 + n))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After some exploration I found the way (two variants):

```
l = [{:a, 3}, {:b, 5}, {:c, 3}, {:a, 6}, {:b, 3}, {:a, 3}]

l |> Enum.group_by(fn {key, _value}-> key end)
  |> Enum.map( fn {group, value_list} -> {group, Enum.reduce(value_list, 0, fn {_key,value}, acc -> acc + value end)} end)

l |> Enum.group_by(fn {key, _value}-> key end, fn {_key, value}-> value end)
  |> Enum.map( fn {group, value_list} -> {group, Enum.reduce(value_list, 0, fn value, acc -> acc + value end)} end)
```

Both ways lead to the same result. However, the first better exemplifies where one can define what is the category based on the input data, and the latter also shows how to process the value in the original `l` list before it is accumulated.

Hope this helps to others.

Comment: `Enum.reduce(value_list, 0, fn value, acc -> acc = acc + value end)` is a long way to write `Enum.sum(value_list)` (and also the `acc = ` is redundant, hence why you get a warning).

Comment: Thanks. You are right with "acc =". I will try to remove it from my comment. 
You are also right that simple sum could be done by using `Enum.sum`. I am learning, thank you for this comment. 
In my particular case I needed to do categories not just through the keys. I needed to compute the category on fly (simple example could be using as category `div(k,7)` instead of `k`). Next, I needed to accumulate not just simple sum of `value`, but function of `value`. Everett's solution covers all this aspects in one.